# Android - Encrypt variables before the go to RAM

Tags: security, encryption, memory

I need to work with encrypted variables so that if the os is not secure or a attavk at the ram is carried out it is hard to access sensitive data.
So my question is how that would be possible?

Comment: 1. Hold the data encrypted. 2. Decrypt the data to process a single transaction as quick as possible. 3. Clean all memory afterwards. 4. Go back to 1.

Comment: yeah that would be my idea to but I dont know how to do that

Comment: Do it step by step. Start with data encryption/decryption in Android. Search for a popular library which is easy to use. Maybe on SO? : ) Just note, this question is to broad to be answered in a single post. Too many assumptions would have to be made.